# Node.js / localhost / port / forwardhq

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to access my localhost Node.js app running on 0.0.0.0:3000 from mobile and tablets on my Wifi network or potentially using a service like www.forwardhq.com

However, none of the above works.

The ONLY way the app will run is by typing "localhost:3000" into the browser.
Typing "0.0.0.0:3000" or "127.0.0.1:3000" does not resolve.

The only entry in my hosts file is:
255.255.255.255     broadcasthost

I'm on Mac OS 10.10 using Express 4.
Firewall and network sharing is disabled.

This is how I start the server:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('server running: ' + JSON.stringify(server.address())); // server running: {"address":"0.0.0.0","family":"IPv4","port":3000}
});
```

App runs great, but why can't I load it on 0.0.0.0:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000? When using forwardhq Tunnel I just get a white screen.

However I can see in the console that the Node app gets called:
GET / 307 9.037 ms - -

But just a white screen..

Answer (score 0):

Two hours in and I realise my middleware is the culprit:

```
app.use(forceDomain({
    hostname: 'localhost:3000'
}));
```